# How to change materials in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have stuck a bit on a material change in my Unity project.
I have an object with 8 materials on it, I want to change material number 5 when button pressed.
Following code doesn't work:

```
objectToPaint.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[4] = availableMaterials[i];
```

when I do:

```
objectToPaint.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = availableMaterials[i];
```

it will change only 1st material and also proves, triggers are working perfectly. Any suggestions?

Comment: **I have an object with 8 materials on it** That is not good if that object is a 3D Mesh. You have to bake the textures into one and use just one material with that one texture. If you don't do this now, you will come back later on asking why your game is too slow.

Comment: it's not a game, it's a VR Project, simple demo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after a lot of tries and errors, found that you can't change just 1 material in array. I had to assign entire array to temporary array, change desired material and then assign temporary array to the object.

Answer (score 8):

You have to change `renderer.materials`, instead of changing `renderer.material`

As I consider, this should work

```
Material[] mats = renderer.materials; 
mats[4] = availableMaterials[i]; 
renderer.materials = mats;
```